# Understanding exothermic reactions (e.g. combustion) using Newton's laws

Tags: classical-mechanics, physical-chemistry

When reactants undergo exothermic reactions, e.g. combustion of hydrocarbons, energy is conserved when some energy in the chemical bonds of the reactants is transformed into kinetic energy of the products.

Then some of the products would have gained an increase in kinetic energy (i.e. its velocity has changed) meaning that a net force is exerted on these same products (and in action-reaction pairs so that both Newton's third law and conservation of linear momentum hold). My question is, what is the nature of this force, i.e. what is its origin?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

When the bonds break, the constituents are no longer in a bound state. The system is no longer in a well.
[image]

This energy profile comes due to the electromagnetic interaction between the constituents. So the origin of the force, like with almost all of chemical reactions, is the **electromagnetic force**.

Answer (score 0):

...

> meaning that a net force is exerted on these same products (and in
> action-reaction pairs so that both Newton's third law and conservation
> of linear momentum hold).

The source is electromagnetic force, but you have to note that the third law and momentum conservation don't apply if you look only at the scattered masses. Part of the momentum goes to the EM radiation emmited during the reaction.